# how to refer back to created browser instance

Tags: vba, vbscript

I create a browser like so, and manually navigate to the web page I need to be.  I intend to automatically pull certain elements once I get to the page I need to be on via a seperate macro

```
Sub Test()


Set CAS = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer                     ' create a browser
CAS.Visible = True ' make it visible

CAS.navigate "http://intraneturl"

Do Until CAS.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
```

This works fine, then I do

```
Public Sub Gather

Set HTMLDoc2 = CAS.document.frames("top").document

Call Timer1

With HTMLDoc2
.getElementById("tab4").FirstChild.Click
End With

Call Timer2


Dim fir, las, add1, add2, cit, stat, zi As String

Dim First As Variant
Dim Last As Variant
Dim addr1 As Variant
Dim addr2 As Variant
Dim city As Variant
Dim Thisstate As Variant
Dim Zip As Variant

Call Timer2

Set HTMLDoc = CAS.document.frames("MainFrame").document

Call Timer2

With HTMLDoc

First = .getElementsByName("IndFirst")
Last = .getElementsByName("IndLast")
addr1 = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_Line1")
addr2 = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_Line2")
city = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_City")
Thisstate = .getElementsByName("cmb_Add_State")
Zip = .getElementsByName("txtAdd_Zip")

End With



fir = First.Value
las = Last.Value
add1 = addr1.Value
add2 = addr2.Value
cit = city.Value
stat = Thisstate.Value
zi = Zip.Value

'navigate back to start page

 With HTMLDoc2
.getElementById("tab3").FirstChild.Click
End With
End Sub
```

This works the first time, but after the first time, I get "Object variable or with block variable not set" when trying to run the gather() sub again, on a different web page that contains similar information. Any Ideas as to what im doing wrong?

Comment: Where are CAS, HTMLDoc, and HTMLDoc2 defined? Are you using `Option Explicit`? I'd guess you are using public variables which aren't being reset correctly after they are `Set` before the next time you call it.

Comment: Also, have you tried narrowing your problem down to specific lines of code? Try commenting portions out to see if you can isolate your problem.

Comment: i have tried module scope for these: (they are above the sub tags, commented out option explicit) `'Option Explicit` `Dim CAS As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` `Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument` `Dim HTMLDoc2 As MSHTML.HTMLDocument` The error "object variable or with block variable not set" occurs on: `Set HTMLDoc2 = CAS.document.frames("top").document` the second time i try running Gather().  Are you saying I need to set htmldoc2 = nothing when im finished?

Comment: Just to be sure: does the frame "top" exist on the different web page that contains similar information as well? Is myFrame Not Nothing? dim myFrame Set myFrame = CAS.document.frames("top")

Comment: The top frame always exists.  I think this has something to do with not creating Internet Explorer as an object, since the second time around im trying to reference to it, but it doesnt see it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The error "object variable or with block variable not set" occurs on: Set HTMLDoc2 = CAS.document.frames("top").document the second time i try running Gather()."

This is probably one of three things:

1. CAS is no longer an object
   To check this, set a breakpoint on the line, press ctr+G in the VBA Editor and type `?CAS Is Nothing` in the Immediate Window; the result should be False; if it is True CAS is no longer an object
2. Like Daniel Dusek suggested, make sure CAS.document.frames("top") is an actual element on the page.
   To check this, open the webpage you are trying to script, press F12 in Internet Explorer, click on the arrow in the toolbar and click on the "top" frame element in the webpage, switch back to the Developer Tool and look at the line highlighted. Make sure the frame element is named "top".
3. The HTML hasn't fully loaded when you try to reference the frame element. Set a longer delay or a loop.

i.e. (untested):

```
    Do Until HtmlDoc2 Is Nothing = false
      Set HTMLDoc2 = CAS.document.frames("top").document 
    Loop
```

Maybe the more important question is why manually navigate to another page? Can't you automate that part of your process too?

Comment: thank you for your help, CAS was no longer an object and that was the problem. Ended up fixing it thanks to everyones help! Automating navigation is kind of clunky since it requires timeouts and stuff, and the database is slow.  The browser state = ready isnt as trustworthy as you would think it should be

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Just one other note on browser state that might help you or someone else in the future (I learned it the hard way). Browser state tests for a successful response from the server. Once a successful response is received, your `Do Until ReadyState` code will exit the loop. However, this doesn't mean that the HTML has fully loaded in the browser. So if you try to reference an HTML element that hasn't been created (maybe by a Javascript function) or hasn't loaded yet, you can still get an error using `ReadyState`.

Comment: yeah, i add in a pause of time afterwards, but i think what i should do is test a .getelementsbid element on page, that i KNOW will exist on the page, and wait until that element exists to keep running code.  Now sure what the downside of that is.